# Variable exchange in definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, normal-distribution

In a proof that any univariate normal random variable $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is a linear transformation of the standard normal $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, I've seen the following:

Let $X$ be a normal random variable with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$, and let $Z = (X - \mu)/\sigma$. Then

$$
\Pr(Z \leq z) = \Pr(X \leq \sigma z + \mu) =
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\sigma z + \mu}
\exp \left(
- \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( \frac{t - \mu}{\sigma} \right)^2
\right) \mathrm{d}t
$$

Substituting $x = (t - \mu) / \sigma$ and using $\mathrm{d}t = \sigma \mathrm{d}x$, we obtain the distribution function of standard normal.

My question is related to the substitution. $x = (t - \mu) / \sigma$ looks straightforward, but where does $\mathrm{d}t = \sigma \mathrm{d}x$ come from? (it's been a while sice my calculus classes)

Comment: $t=\sigma x+\mu$ so $\frac  {d t} {dx}=\sigma$.

Comment: Thanks! But $\frac{dt}{dx}$ is not really a fraction, so why can we treat it like that? (Maybe that's a known trick?)

Comment: $\int f(t) dt=\int f(t) \frac {dt} {dx} dx$ is true.

Comment: Do you have a good reference that explains this equality? (Looks like some fundamental theorem of calculus or similar?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out, it's simply integration by change of variables (substitution). Fot the sake of completeness, we want to solve this:
$$
\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\sigma z + \mu}
\exp \left(
- \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( \frac{t - \mu}{\sigma} \right)^2
\right) \mathrm{d}t
$$
Let $u(t) = \frac{t - \mu}{\sigma}$. Then $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{\sigma}$ and $\mathrm{d}t = \sigma\ \mathrm{d}u$, which we plug back to the integral.

The lower bound remains $-\infty$ and for the upper bound, $u(\sigma z + \mu) = \frac{(\sigma z + \mu) - \mu}{\sigma} = z$, so we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
&= \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}
\int_{u(-\infty)}^{u(\sigma z + \mu)}
\exp \left(
- \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( u \right)^2
\right) \sigma\ \mathrm{d}u
\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\int_{-\infty}^{z}
\exp \left(
- \frac{u^2}{2} \right) \mathrm{d}u
\\
&= \Phi(u)
\end{aligned}
$$
which is indeed a CDF of standard normal.